# Excel: How to match numbers in two columns

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet and two columns. Column B has a set of numbers from 1 to 3500. In Column A, it is blank. I have a random set of numbers that are within the range in column B. When I paste this set of random numbers in column A, I want the numbers to land in the cell next to the same number in  column B.

Issue:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 4 | 6 |

Goal:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |

Ive tried to do a MATCH and VLOOK formula but I don't think those are what I need to do.

Comment: Using worksheet formulas, it is not possible to ***paste*** a range of values into Column A and then move them to other cells.  You could have the random set of numbers in a different column, or you could use VBA. Which would you prefer?

Comment: You can paste random numbers in column C, and then `VLOOKUP` to check if a number is in column B.

Comment: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,C$1:C$17,1,FALSE),"")`